# Is there Hierarchy WordPress custom post types?

Tags: wordpress

I am researching how to work with WordPress 3.x custom post types.  I see how easy it is to create content types such as "case", "ticket", "image", etc, etc.  But it seems like I am putting all my eggs in one basket.  Lets say I create a new custom post type "image" so I can create galleries.  Is there a way to setup multiple galleries with those images? Is there any way to setup sub-classes of the post type "images" so I can distinguish one group image from another and create multiple galleries?
I thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: probably better luck over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zxt I am very confused about which questions I can ask here.  Is there a guideline somewhere?

Comment: @ryy705...Your question is/was very appropriate here. zxt, I believe, was just trying to point you to where you might get a quicker response.

Answer (score 0):

ryy...custom post types are very flexible. You can distinguish posts by using custom taxonomies (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/). Wherever you are within the WP context, you can always retrieve your custom posts using the WP_Query class (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query), which is extremely flexible and easy to use. You are doing the right thing by creating a custom post type for the things you've mentioned. You can keep everything well organized that way and will be able to do a lot with the data that you put into it.